# pip3 not found in Tensorflow environment: "-bash: pip3: command not found"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ipython, tensorflow, jupyter

I'm following instructions to create a Tensorflow environment for a Machine Learning course, with python 3.5, ipython and jupyter.

I created a Tenserflow environment with python 3.5 using `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5`. That worked.

Then I ran `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`. That also worked.

Then I installed ipython with `conda install ipython`, which also worked fine.

However, when I ran `pip3 install jupyter`, I got error message `bash: pip3: command not found`.

I found a few posts about variations on pip3 problems and (within the Tensorflow environment):

- When I type `pip --version`, it tells me I have version 8.1.2
- When I try `locate pip3`, I get `WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist`

I tried using `pip-3.2` as recommended in one of the other questions' solutions (which worked for that OP), and I get the same `command not found` error message.

I'm using OS X  10.8.5

Comment: As you've created the environment with Python 3 (`python=3.5`), `pip` is `pip3`. So just run `pip install jupyter`. You can also use conda, with `conda install jupyter`.

Answer (score -1):

pip is different from pip3. So you might need to install it if it can't be found.  If it is installed run this:

```
sudo updatedb
```

this will update the locate function.

if you're using conda why do you want to install it with pip anyways?

Jupyter is the new version of ipython.  running conda install ipython installs ipython (now jupyter).

Comment: pip and pip3 are different in some situations, but inside a Python 3 environment, they are the same (if both exist).